# Optimisation: Conversion from int to Roman Numeral

Tags: c#, performance

A while ago I made a post about optimising the multiplication of every number in an array by 2. With everyone's help I was able to go from 1,500 ns (LINQ) to 30 ns.

So I thought I'd try something harder. The conversion of an int to a Roman Numeral. I have already tried several algorithms one that tested if a numeral is in prefix form like (IV or XC) before adding to the numeral and one that once 4 numerals of the same type were added it backtracked. The following is the best I've come up with where I split the number into units and map each unit to a Numeral. `x` in the `Numeral Map` is the power of 10 and `y` is the amount of that unit.

Any kind of performance optimisation is welcome and don't worry about readability this is just for fun.

The code:

```
public static Numeral ToNumeral(this int x)
    {
        if (x == 0) return Zero;

        int remaining = x;
        int index = 3;

        int divisor = 1000;


        StringBuilder numeralBuilder = new();

        do
        {
            int digit = remaining / divisor;

            remaining -= digit * divisor;

            divisor /= 10;

            numeralBuilder.Append(NumeralMap.Value[index--, digit]);

        } while (index >= 0);


        return new(x, numeralBuilder.ToString());
    }


    private static readonly Lazy<string[,]> NumeralMap = new(new string[4, 10]
    {
        {"","I", "II", "III", "IV","V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX" },
        {"","X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC" },
        {"","C", "CC", "CCC", "CD","D" ,"DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM" },
        {"","M", "MM", "MMM",  "", "",  "",   "",      "",     "" }
    });
```

Benchmark:

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason why you made the `NumeralMap` lazy? Ran a crude benchmark and doing it not lazy saves 1-2%, not massive but still

Comment: Also it would be nice if you could include the `Numeral` type and the benchmark code you used. This would make it easier to replicate your findings and compare alternate approaches

Answer (score 1):

## memoize

You're unlikely to see more than a few thousand distinct input values.

So allocate a hash or an array,
then accept conversion requests.
Compute the corresponding result
as slowly as you like -- it won't matter.
[Memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization#Some_other_considerations)
the result and return it.

Now if you're ever asked for that same conversion again,
it costs a hash probe or an array de-reference,
and you're off to the races!

---

Use an [LRU](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)
technique if you're concerned about
aging out ancient unpopular requests.

Comment: Memoization is a really good suggestion. However this optimisation works best when we have specific details about the application it will be running in. As you say If I made a million calls to this method and there are only about 3000 possible numerals then caching those numerals is a no brainer. But what If all I want to do with it is to iterate all Numerals from 1 to 1000 and never touch it again? Then we'd probably be hurting the performance. :)

Comment: Yeah, an LRU can limit our memory consumption if we see an access pattern (like counting to 1000) which differs from what we thought at design time the "typical" pattern would be. Monitoring cache hit counters is another way to mitigate such lossage -- if in the last hundred calls we got zero cache hits, then maybe set a `disabled = 50` counter, and don't bother memoizing any results until we have decremented that counter down to zero.

Comment: Still +1 though, this is definitely worth mentioning.

Comment: Very good point but there many not be any discernible pattern at all and the cache may have 0 hits. In this case decrementing a counter and performing the last 100 calls check will hurt performance. I understand these are fringe cases and in practice caching would be beneficial, however I am more looking for optimisations in the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

Ok been a while but managed to make further optimisations to the method. Splitting the Conversion map into 4 sub-maps made it possible to only perform one bounds check at the start of the method then use unsafe code to quickly access the other maps after. Managed to remove the StringBuilder and replace it with spans to avoid the alocation.

```
 public override string? ToString()
        {
            if (Value == 0) return "Nulla";

            if (Value > 3999) return null;


            int remaining = Value;


            int digit = remaining / 1000;

            remaining -= digit * 1000;

            ref var thousandsArrayPtr = ref MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference(ThousandsMap.Value);

            ref var thousandsPtr = ref Unsafe.Add(ref thousandsArrayPtr, digit);

            var thousandsSpan = thousandsPtr.AsSpan();


            digit = remaining / 100;

            remaining -= digit * 100;

            ref var hundredsArrayPtr = ref MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference(HundredsMap.Value);

            ref var hundredsPtr = ref Unsafe.Add(ref hundredsArrayPtr, digit);

            var hundredsSpan = hundredsPtr.AsSpan();



            digit = remaining / 10;

            remaining -= digit * 10;

            ref var tensArrayPtr = ref MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference(TensMap.Value);

            ref var tensPtr = ref Unsafe.Add(ref tensArrayPtr, digit);

            var tensSpan = tensPtr.AsSpan();


            ref var unitArrayPtr = ref MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference(UnitMap.Value);

            ref var unitPtr = ref Unsafe.Add(ref unitArrayPtr, remaining);

            var unitSpan = unitPtr.AsSpan();


            return string.Concat(thousandsSpan, hundredsSpan, tensSpan, unitSpan);
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If we completely unroll the loop we can avoid doing bounds checks and some unnecessary assignments and operations.

```
 if (x == 0) return Zero;

        int remaining = x;

        StringBuilder numeralBuilder = new();


        int digit = remaining / 1000;

        remaining -= digit * 1000;

        numeralBuilder.Append(NumeralMap.Value[3, digit]);


        digit = remaining / 100;

        remaining -= digit * 100;

        numeralBuilder.Append(NumeralMap.Value[2, digit]);



        digit = remaining / 10;

        remaining -= digit * 10;

        numeralBuilder.Append(NumeralMap.Value[1, digit]);



        numeralBuilder.Append(NumeralMap.Value[0, remaining]);


        return new(x, numeralBuilder.ToString());
    }


    private static readonly Lazy<string[,]> NumeralMap = new(new string[4, 10]
    {
        {"","I", "II", "III", "IV","V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX" },
        {"","X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC" },
        {"","C", "CC", "CCC", "CD","D" ,"DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM" },
        {"","M", "MM", "MMM",  "", "",  "",   "",      "",     "" }
    });
```

Benchmark:

[image]

If we could somehow run the algorithm without heap allocations that would be fantastic.